# Boost Array - conversion to BYTE

Tags: boost, boost-asio, shared-ptr, boost-thread

So i have this: boost::array data_;

How do i convert it to normal BYTE/Char buffer or how do i print the data inside without converting it , using printf?

How can i compare it with other normal chracter buffer for example "hello".
It will be also very helpfull to know how does boost::array work, (i am creating boost async.tcp server).

I have tried some things but i was unable to print the characters inside the buffer, i'm new to boost.

I could not find much documentation about boost.

Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

The boost::array class is a parameterized type, meaning that the full type name of a variable of this type is something like `boost::array<char,10>` for an array containing 10 elements of type char, or `boost::array<float,100>` for an array containing 100 elements of type float.

If you happen to have a variable `data_` of some type `boost::array<`*T*`,`*N*`>` where *T* is `char`, then printing out the characters in it is easy:

```
std::cout.write(data_.data(), data_.size());
```

If *T* is `wchar`, you could do

```
std::wcout.write(data_.data(), data_.size());
```

If your particular `boost::array` type contains some other element type *T*, you need to consider how you would want to print out the elements. For example, if your happy with the default stream representation of the type, you may do something like

```
for (auto element : _data) {
    std::cout << element << "\n";
}
```

to print out one element per line.

You can find the documentation of the `boost::array` class at http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_53_0/doc/html/boost/array.html